# How to avoid stack overflow during CPS conversion?

Tags: f#, compiler-construction, lisp

I'm writing a transformation from Scheme subset to CPS language. It is implemented in F#. On big input programs conversion fails by stack overflow.

I'm using some sort of algorithm described in the paper [Compiling with Continuations](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/compiling-with-continuations-continued/).
I've tried to increase maximum stack size of the working thread up to 50 MB, then it works.

**Maybe there some way to modify the algorithm, so that I won't need to tune stack size?**

For example, the algorithm transforms

```lisp
(foo (bar 1) (bar 2))
```

to

```lisp
(let ((c1 (cont (r1)
           (let ((c2 (cont (r2)
                  (foo halt r1 r2))))
            (bar c2 2)))))
 (bar c1 1))
```

where `halt` is a final continuation which finishes the program.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly fails? the conversion itself or the code generated after the conversion?

Comment: The conversion itself fails

Comment: Related: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/on-recursion-continuations-and-trampolines/

Comment: Sounds like you may be using linear recursion that isn't being (or cannot be) tail optimized.

Comment: Rewrite the algorithm in your Scheme subset; then run the original F# version to CPS-transform it to boostrap it. Maybe that will cure it. :)

Comment: @Kaz, what do you mean be linear recursion? Tail recursion? If yes, then you are right... F# can make tail optimization only if function calls itself in tail position, but if it calls other function, then normal call is emitted

Comment: @Hanik Not all linear recursion is tail recursive. Think of the naive recursive implementation of factorial, where the inductive case is: N * fact(N - 1). That consumes stack proportional to N; it requires a refactoring to be tail recursive because the call isn't in tail position; it has to return in order for the result to be multiplied by N. If you do anything of this sort where N is linked to the size of your input, you then have stack consumption proportional to your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your actual problems has simple solutions to avoid heavy stack consumption, so please don't mind adding details. However, without more knowledge about your particular code, here is a general approach to reduce the stack consumption in a recursive programs, based on trampolines and continuations.

#### Walker

Here is a typical recursive function that is not trivially tail-recursive, written in Common Lisp because I don't know F#:

```
(defun walk (form transform join)
  (typecase form
    (cons (funcall join
                   (walk (car form) transform join)
                   (walk (cdr form) transform join)))
    (t (funcall transform form))))
```

The code is however quite simple, hopefully, and walks a tree made of cons cells:

1. if the form is a cons-cell, recursively walk on the car (resp. cdr) and join the results
2. Otherwise, apply a transform on the value

For example:

```
(walk '(a (b c d) 3 2 (a 2 1) 0)
      (lambda (u) (and (numberp u) u))
      (lambda (a b) (if a (cons a b) (or a b))))

=> (3 2 (2 1) 0)
```

The code walks the form, and retain only numbers, but preserves (non-empty) nesting.

Calling `trace` on `walk` with the above example shows a maximal depth of 8 nested calls.

#### Continuations and trampoline

Here is an adapted version, called
`walk/then`, that walks a form as previously, and when a result is
available, calls `then` on it. Here `then` is a **continuation**.

The function also returns a *thunk*, i.e. a parameterless closure.
What happens is that when we return the closure, the stack is unwound, 
and when we apply the *thunk* it will 
start from a fresh stack, but having advanced in the computation
(I usually picture someone walking up an escalator that goes down).
The fact that we return a thunk to reduce the number of stack frames is part of the **trampoline**.

The `then` function takes a value, namely 
the result that the current walk eventually will return.
The result is thus passed *down* the stack, and what is
returned at each step is a thunk function.

Nesting continuations allows to capture the complex behaviour of `transform`/`join`, by pushing the remaining parts of the computation in nested continuations.

```
(defun walk/then (form transform join then)
  (typecase form
    (cons (lambda ()
            (walk/then (car form) transform join
                       (lambda (v)
                         (walk/then (cdr form) transform join
                                    (lambda (w)
                                      (funcall then (funcall join v w))))))))
    (t (funcall then (funcall transform form)))))
```

For example, `(walk/then (car form) transform join (lambda (v) ...))` reads as follows: *walk the car of form with 
arguments `transform` and `join`, and eventually call `(lambda (v) ...)` on the result; namely, walk down the cdr, and then join both results; eventually, call the input `then` on the joined result*.

What is missing is a way to continually call the returned thunk until exhaustion; here is it 
with a loop, but this could easily be a tail-recursive function:

```
(loop for res = 
     (walk/then '(a (b c d) 3 2 (a 2 1) 0)
                (lambda (u) (and (numberp u) u))
                (lambda (a b) (if a (cons a b) (or a b)))
                #'identity)
   then (typecase res (function (funcall res)) (t res))
   while (functionp res)
   finally (return res))
```

The above returns `(3 2 (2 1) 0)`, and the depth of the trace never goes over 2 when tracing `walk/then`.

See [Eli Bendersky's article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/on-recursion-continuations-and-trampolines/) for another take at this, in Python.

Comment: The problem is that my algorithm already has a continuation as a parameter: ``transform (expr  : Expr) (continuation : Var -> Expr)``. I guess I need to add another continuation.

Comment: @Hanik I guess so, but honestly this is hard to answer for a random person like me, what I am suggesting might not be easy to apply in your case;

Answer (score 1):

I've converted algorithm to trampoline form. It looks like FSM.
There is a loop, which looks at the current state, makes some manipulations, and goes to another state. Also it uses two stacks for different kind of continuations.

Here is input language (it is a subset of the language I used originally) :

```
// Input language consists of only variables and function applications
type Expr =
    | Var of string
    | App of Expr * Expr list
```

Here is target language:

```
// CPS form - each function gets a continuation,
// added continuation definitions and continuation applications
type Norm =
    | LetCont of name : string * args : string list * body : Norm * inner : Norm
    | FuncCall of func : string * cont : string * args : string list
    | ContCall of cont : string * args : string list
```

Here is original algorithm:

```
// Usual way to make CPS conversion.
let rec transform expr cont =
    match expr with
    | App(func, args) ->
        transformMany (func :: args) (fun vars ->
            let func' = List.head vars
            let args' = List.tail vars
            let c = fresh()
            let r = fresh()
            LetCont(c, [r], cont r, FuncCall(func', c, args')))
    | Var(v) -> cont v

and transformMany exprs cont =
    match exprs with
    | e :: rest ->
        transform e (fun e' ->
            transformMany rest (fun rest' ->
                cont (e' :: rest')))
    | _ -> cont []

let transformTop expr =
    transform expr (fun var -> ContCall("halt", [var]))
```

Here is modified version:

```
type Action =
    | ContinuationVar of Expr * (string -> Action)
    | ContinuationExpr of string * (Norm -> Action)
    | TransformMany of string list * Expr list * (string list -> Action)
    | Result of Norm
    | Variable of string

// Make one action at time and return to top loop
let rec transform2 expr =
    match expr with
    | App(func, args) ->
        TransformMany([], func :: args, (fun vars ->
            let func' = List.head vars
            let args' = List.tail vars
            let c = fresh()
            let r = fresh()
            ContinuationExpr(r, fun expr ->
                Result(LetCont(c, [r], expr, FuncCall(func', c, args'))))))
    | Var(v) -> Variable(v)

// We have two stacks here:
// contsVar for continuations accepting variables
// contsExpr for continuations accepting expressions
let transformTop2 expr =
    let rec loop contsVar contsExpr action =
        match action with
        | ContinuationVar(expr, cont) ->
            loop (cont :: contsVar) contsExpr (transform2 expr)
        | ContinuationExpr(var, contExpr) ->
            let contVar = List.head contsVar
            let contsVar' = List.tail contsVar
            loop contsVar' (contExpr :: contsExpr) (contVar var)
        | TransformMany(vars, e :: exprs, cont) ->
            loop contsVar contsExpr (ContinuationVar(e, fun var ->
                TransformMany(var :: vars, exprs, cont)))
        | TransformMany(vars, [], cont) ->
            loop contsVar contsExpr (cont (List.rev vars))
        | Result(r) ->
            match contsExpr with
            | cont :: rest -> loop contsVar rest (cont r)
            | _ -> r
        | Variable(v) ->
            match contsVar with
            | cont :: rest -> loop rest contsExpr (cont v)
            | _ -> failwith "must not be empty"

    let initial = ContinuationVar(expr, fun var -> Result(ContCall("halt", [var])))
    loop [] [] initial
```